# Netty TCP Server that server multiple requests with just one socket connection 

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

Is it possible to use Netty to implement a TCP server that performs multiple interactions (request-response) with a client using the same socket connection. Any pointers/examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course it should be possible, just don't close the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.. you can send/receive as much messages as you want. Just don't close the channel until you are done.

Comment: so what's the correct way to close the channel in this case. Setting a timeout value ?

Comment: Yes.. You can use the IdleStateHandler for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can do channel.write(object) as many times as necessary before closing the channel. Another thing is you should mention bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive",true) to keep the connection alive